# Upload PDF file via API: Could someone explain what is going on?

Tags: vba, adodb

I found this question and answer:

[How to upload a pdf fil...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77026500/how-to-upload-a-pdf-file-through-a-post-request-using-vba/77524411)

I have adapted solution to my needs. I use it for uploading pdf-files to a financial system and it is working just fine, but there is some code part I don't understand:

```
Dim FieldANme as string
---
Dim File, FILESIZE
Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
ado.Type = 1 'binary
ado.Open
ado.LoadFromFile FilePath
ado.Position = 0
FILESIZE = ado.Size
File = ado.Read
ado.Close

Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
d = "--" + BOUNDARY + vbCrLf
d = d + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""deal_id""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
d = d + DEALID & vbCrLf
d = d + "--" + BOUNDARY + vbCrLf
d = d + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""" + FieldName + """;"
d = d + " filename=""" + fileName + """" + vbCrLf
d = d + "Content-Type: " & CONTENT + vbCrLf + vbCrLf
ado.Type = 1 'binary
ado.Open
ado.Write ToBytes(d)
ado.Write File
ado.Write ToBytes(vbCrLf + "--" + BOUNDARY + "--" + vbCrLf)
ado.Position = 0
```

I have two questions:

1. `Dim FieldName As String`: It is not used. What could it be used for?
2. Could someone explain the ADODB stuff? I understand that the file is digitized - but a PDF file is per default digital?

I did search for explanations but didn't find an explanation.

Comment: `Dim FieldANme as string` looks like a typo, and FieldName *is* used in the code you posted.

Comment: Lots of discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean you may find useful.